# How to connect to index.php file with Express and Node.js

Tags: php, node.js, express

I would like to create a real time application, but I am new to Node.js, Express and Socket.io.
I would like to connect with Express to a file called `index.php`.
Unfortunately I saw that Express connects by default to a file called `index.html`.

This is a part of my **index.js** file:

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');

var app = express();

//App setup
var server = app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log('listening on requests on port 4000');
});

//Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));

//Socket setup
var io = socket(server);
```

This is my **index.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Socket Sender</title>
        <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-gDaozqUvc4HTgo8iZjwth73C6dDDeOJsAgpxBcMpZYztUfjHXpzrpdrHRdVp8ySO" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </head>
<body onload="redirect()">
    <button id="send">Send</button>
    <div id="table_container">
    </div>
    <script language=javascript>
        function redirect(){
          window.location = "index.php";
        }
    </script>
    <!--<script src="/receiver.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I used a workaround to connect to a php file. So the `index.html` should redirect to `index.php` but for some reason the browser only downloads `index.php` and doesn't render that file.

Can help?

Comment: Why do you need to make node start with a php file? Can't you migrate your PHP code to node instead? Anyway, node can't parse PHP so `.php` doesn't have any special meaning (nor does it have any special meaning for the browser either), which means that the browser will just see it as a non-html file and download it instead. You need to set up a web server with PHP support to be able to server PHP files.

Comment: Currently I run Apache and Xampp locally. In the future I should send data to an old PHP application and so for me is important to send the data that I retreive from a database with Express to a PHP file. That's because I should create a real time application that can communicate with PHP files. The PHP files will send the values of session variables to Node.js and depending on these variables Node.js will send in real time data retrieved from a db. For that reason migrating an entire PHP web app to Node.js may require a lot of time.

Comment: Then you should probably use the PHP app as an API (making requests to it from node) like you would to any API and not redirecting the request to the PHP app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ciao Michele,

you can try with a PHP interpreter for NodeJS, it is called php-express.
So, first of all need to install it with:

```
npm install php-express
```

than your project structure must be:

```
./ index.js
--/public/index.html // <--- html file for redirect
--/views/index.php // <--- your php file
```

**index.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var socket = require('socket.io');
var phpExpress = require('php-express')({
    binPath: 'php'
});

var app = express();

//App setup
var server = app.listen(4000, function() {
    console.log('listening on requests on port 4000');
});


app.engine('php', phpExpress.engine);

app.all(/.+\.php$/, phpExpress.router);

//Static files
app.use(express.static('public'));


//Socket setup
var io = socket(server);
```

- in index.html need to append **href** attribute to `window.location`

example of your **index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Socket Sender</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/3.1.1/socket.io.min.js" integrity="sha384-gDaozqUvc4HTgo8iZjwth73C6dDDeOJsAgpxBcMpZYztUfjHXpzrpdrHRdVp8ySO" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body onload="redirect()">
<button id="send">Send</button>
<div id="table_container">
</div>
<script language=javascript>
    function redirect(){
        window.location.href = 'index.php';
    }
</script>
<!--<script src="/receiver.js"></script>-->
</body>
</html>
```

than an example of your `index.php` file

```
<?php

echo "Hello World";

?>
```

as finally run your express web server with:

```
node index.js
```

Comment: php-express doesn't seem to have gotten any updates in the last 5 years, and the latest version is 0.0.3. I wouldn't call that a viable option tbh. And I don't think it makes sense to run a PHP app through Node in the first place. It's better to use it as an API, since they then are more separated and you can switch out one without needing to touch the other.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I've replied to Michele issue, I'm not consulting him for which is the best tecnology for website hosting. He are using express, and have an issue for php file, so this is a solution. :) Don't waste your time bro

Comment: If you see someone recommending (which is what an answer does) a bad solution, you _should_ point that out. Not all answers are created equal. And me writing a comment pointing that out isn't wasting my time. It most likely stops the OP (and future visitors) from wasting their time by trying an insufficient solution that can cause more issues than it solves. I'm here to help people (in the long run), not just to earn rep.